# Unsigned arithmetic in C++

Tags: c++

I just observed a strange phenomenon when doing unsigned arithmetic. It's expected that `b` and `-a` have the same number `4294967286` due to wraparound, but the actual output for `b` and `-a` is `-10` and `4294967286` respectively. Could anyone help give a hint?

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  unsigned int a = 10;
  int b = -a;
  std::cout << b << ", " << -a << std::endl;
}
```

https://repl.it/repls/ExpertDrabOrganization

Comment: Why do you expect that an `int` would have the value 4294967286, which is much larger than the maximum `int`?

Comment: `int b = -a;` -> `unsigned int b = -a;`

Comment: @molbdnilo My fault. I forgot that `b` overflows, too.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`-a` is evaluated in `unsigned` arithmetic, and will be a number *larger* than [`std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max). The unary operator `-` when applied to an `unsigned` type acts more like a modulus operator.

Therefore the behaviour of your program is *implementation defined* due to an out-of-range assignment to an `int`.

Comment: *implementation* defined - I.e. look at the docs, and shout at your implementer if they don't do what they promise.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Since which flashy new standard?

Comment: As old as [C++11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/conv.integral#3). I don't have an earlier draft handy.

Comment: @StoryTeller: I'll change it on your authority: you're far more familiar with the standard than I am.

Comment: @StoryTeller It was implementation-defined in C++03 too.

Comment: @Angew - Interestingly enough, it's implementation defined in a C99 draft I have lying around. It would seem that a *conversion* was always with implementation defined semantics. Overflow in arithmetic with signed types is UB, however, wherever I checked. Curious.

Comment: gcc implementation defined behavior: [The value is reduced module 2^N](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.2.0/gcc/Integers-implementation.html#Integers-implementation). So the same for clang. For MSVC this behavior is not ensured: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/demotion-of-integers?view=vs-2017

Comment: MSVC says "When signed variables are converted to unsigned and vice versa, the bit patterns remain the same." so the example in the question is well-defined in MSVC (and will have the same result as in gcc/clang). What is not 100% clear from the MSVC documentation is what happens when a value is truncated *and* converted to signed in a single operation.